# isAlive() returns false

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class `MyTunnel` which extends `Thread` class :

```
public class MyTunnel extends Thread {
    protected Object obj;
    public MyTunnel() {
        super(MyTunnel.class.getName());
        obj = new Object();
        prepare();
    }
    public void prepare() {
        System.out.println("Before starting...");
        start();
        synchronized(obj) {
            try {
                obj.wait(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error while waiting thread to start");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("After starting...");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("running...");
    }

}
```

When I run following code on main thread:

```
System.out.println("Before creating tunnel...");
MyTunnel tunnel = new MyTunnel();
System.out.println("After creating tunnel...");

System.out.println("Is tunnel alive ? " + tunnel.isAlive());
```

I see print out like this:

```
Before creating tunnel...
Before starting...
running...
After starting...
After creating tunnel...
Is tunnel alive ? false
```

My question is, why `tunnel.isAlive()` returns false (in last print out message)?

But if I change `prepare()` function to:

```
public void prepare() {
    System.out.println("Before starting...");
    start();
    System.out.println("After starting...");
}
```

run the code again, `tunnel.isAlive()` then returns true. Why?

Comment: Your thread only does one thing: writes running. Then it's dead and of course not running anymore, especially after three seconds.

Comment: But why removing the "obj.wait(3000)" would result in isAlive() = true? It also  does the same thing in run()

Comment: Because then you don't wait 3s to check it after starting the thread and the thread may still be alive. May being the operative word. It may not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The first scenario:

Your current ("main") thread starts the new thread, then the call `obj.wait(3000);` causes *the current thread to wait* with a timeout of 3 seconds. **It's *not* the new thread that waits!**

As the current thread waits, the new thread is executed. It only writes "running..." and finishes very quickly.

Thus, the "main" thread is resumed (after 3 seconds), the new thread is already dead, so `isAlive()` returns `false`.

### The second scenario:

Your current ("main") thread starts the new thread *and continues executing.*

The new thread *may or may not run* while the main thread does just a few `System.out.println()` calls.

Thus, there's a chance that the new thread is not yet executed and the new thread is still alive, so `isAlive()` returns `true`.

Note that it *may* happen that the new thread is executed just after having been started in the second scenario. So even in the second scenario `isAlive()` *may* return `false`, but the chances are lower than in the first one (-> race conditions).

---

P.S. if you include any "heavy" operation in the second scenario just before calling `isAlive()`, then it's likely that the result is `false`. Pls try the following:

```
    System.out.println("Before creating tunnel...");
    final MyTunnel tunnel = new MyTunnel();
    System.out.println("After creating tunnel...");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        System.out.print("");
    }

    System.out.println("Is tunnel alive ? " + tunnel.isAlive()); // returns false on my machine
```